# Players and deck methods in a card game

Tags: oop

I'm programming a card game (of Uno / Mau Mau type) and I have this design problem:

The deck contains two stacks of cards, one of them shows faces, the other shows backs. When a game is in progress and a player throws a card, it should go onto the "faces" stack. However, when the game is finished, the cards of the last player should go back onto the "backs" stack.

1) Should the deck have two methods for adding cards (addToFacesStack and addToBacksStack)

or

2) Should the deck have an addCards method and decide itself which stack the cards should go onto (the deck would have to know the state of the game - in progress/finished)?

Also, when the game is in progress and a player (who knows the rules and selects cards to play accordingly) throws card(s) onto the "faces" stack, should the deck "re-check" whether the player's move is valid?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Caroline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be asking the question: ***should the model know about the game logic or just the state of the game?***

If **YES**, then you need to include the game logic inside your model, hence you can have only the `addCards` method, and the `Deck` will decide where to add the card(s). But, in this case the game model and game logic are tightly coupled. If you were to use the same model for another variation of the game (with a different logic), this option would not be appropriate.

If **NO**, then you can follow the [**Boundary - Control - Entity**](http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~pearce/modules/patterns/enterprise/ecb/ecb.htm) design pattern. Here, you need to have separate methods for adding cards to the first or second stack. And encode the game logic into your controller objects, which would know the rules of the game. Using this pattern, you can reuse the same model and just employ different controllers based on the game being played.

Regarding your question:

> Also, when the game is in progress and a player (who knows the rules and selects cards to play accordingly) throws card(s) onto the "faces" stack, should the deck "re-check" whether the player's move is valid?

In this case, you can have a controller that will check whether the move is valid or not. No need to encode the logic inside the model.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable comments!

Comment: I've chosen the "NO" option of your answer and came up with this: [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43977777/cards-and-deck-in-a-card-game-inherit-or-not)